# MAMP PRO 3 and share url with noip

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I would like to share a website on my mac with somebody outside my LAN
i setup an account on noip and enable my host for noip sharing, but actually i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

I have found this guide:

[no-ip guide](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/diy-hosting-using-no-ip-mamp/)

I hope it will be useful.